# Parse `NaN` Json.parse configuration

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I am trying to parse a JSON object with a `NaN` using play-json in Scala.

```
import play.api.libs.json._
val s = """{"a": NaN}"""
val p = Json.parse(s)
```

This errors with

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Non-standard token
>   'NaN': enable JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS to allow 
>   at [Source: {"a": NaN}; line: 1, column: 10]
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702)
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558)
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1884)
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:749)
>   play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(JacksonJson.scala:179)
>   play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(JacksonJson.scala:128)
>   play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(JacksonJson.scala:123)
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3786)
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2115)
>   play.api.libs.json.jackson.JacksonJson$.parseJsValue(JacksonJson.scala:235)
>   play.api.libs.json.StaticBinding$.parseJsValue(StaticBinding.scala:16)
>   play.api.libs.json.Json$.parse(Json.scala:171)

**Question:** I am not sure where should I enable the configuration to allow non-standard parsing.

(scala 2.11, com.typesafe.play:play-json_2.11:2.6.9)

Comment: [Since Play doesn't support NaN](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1513), I would avoid this wherever possible. You shouldn't be using or expecting NaN in Scala or Play.

Comment: This is part of a request object I want to parse.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 choices:

1) Enable the `ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS` for you jackson mapper - looks like it's [not supported](https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/how-to-enable-allow-non-numeric-numbers/2199) through play-json, but if you parse the json "manually", you can control it, like that:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.Json4sScalaModule

val jsonString = """{"price": NaN}"""

val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
// Configure NaN here
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS, true)
mapper.registerModule(new Json4sScalaModule)

val json = mapper.readValue(jsonString, classOf[JValue])
```

2) Modifying the json and convert all `NaN` substrings to null. Then parse it with play-json.